# how to implement implement deferred deep linking in electron

Tags: electron, windows-installer, deep-linking, electron-builder

Trying to find information on how to implement deferred deep linking in electron app but can't find it in the official electron documentation.
We have an electronic application. I need the following behavior: when a user tries to open a link of this type -> custom-protocol: // some-data in the browser, if the application is not installed, then automatically download the application and, after installation, pass the parameters contained in the link (some-data) to the application. Can anyone suggest how to implement this in electronic or a link to the documentation or show some abstract example of implementation

Comment: I don't think the NSIS tag is relevant, nothing here is NSIS specific.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [custom protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/understanding-protocols#application-protocols) are stored in the registry. This is a chicken and egg problem because your application already has to be installed on the system for the registry entry to exist.

If you rewrite your application as a UWP app (lol) you might be able to check with [getInstalledRelatedApps](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/) to see if the app is already installed.

If you want to streamline how your application is installed from the web, consider using [ClickOnce](https://textslashplain.com/2019/01/02/demystifying-clickonce/).

Answer (score 0):

So basically you just want a way to pass some query params to your application when installed from your website.

You can do this if you [package your electron application as an MSIX](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/electron-msix.html). Check out the article below from Microsoft, that documents the process:

- [Passing query params to an MSIX packaged app](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/passing-installation-parameters-to-a-windows-application-with/ba-p/1719829)